# How to submit custom fields that are added in the right pane to your plugin?

Tags: control-panel, saveentry, entry-form

I'm making my first Craft plugin.

I have added custom fields to the right of an entry form with the `cp.entries.edit.right-pane` hook ("Share on..").

[image]

But I can't seem to find how to 'transfer' these values to my own plugin and to save them in my own table. The return value of several events I tried (ex. entries.saveEntry) are most of the time an EntryModel which do not include my custom fields.

And I guess making a custom fieldtype is a little overkill?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the answer, correct me if I'm wrong but you can access your post data in your plugin with:

```
craft()->request->getPost('fields')
```

Not sure if this is the recommended way.